# can you please tell me if my code to find the ;largest and the smallest element in an array is efficient enough or not..?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

the efficiency of the code and time complexity? I am running while loops with if and else statements to find the largest and smallest integer instead of for loops I just want to know if my code is efficient enough or I need to use for loops, I also want to know if there is any shortcut to find time complexity like for loop - it is n^2, while loop -n, and examples for O(log(n)) and O(log(n)) and how to find them would be helpful too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of values in an array : ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter values in an Araay :");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (i < n && j < n) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
            j = arr[i];
            k = arr[i + 1];
        } else if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) {
            j = arr[i + 1];
            k = arr[i];
        }

        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("the largest element is : " + j);
    System.out.println("the smallest element is : " + k);

}
```

Comment: What is efficient enough for you might not be efficient enough for me. Seriously, there's heaps of work out on the internet on efficient sorting. I'm guessing you didn't test your code, let alone on negative numbers.

Comment: If you are only interested in the largest and smallest elements, there is no need to sort the array at all. Iterate through the array once; keep a variable with a candidate for the smallest element; when you encounter a new element, compare it to your current candidate, and keep the smaller of the two. Likewise for largest element.

Comment: You don't even need to create the array. You can just read the values and keep track of min and max.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is more complicated than it should be. More than that it doesn't seem to be working properly. 
One approach to find the smallest / largest number is presented below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass{
  public static int findMax(int[] array){
     int max = int[0];
     for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
         if(array[i] > max){
           max = array[i];
         }
      }
      return max;
  }

  public static int findMin(int[] array){
     int min = int[0];
     for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
         if(array[i] < min){
           min = array[i];
         }
      }
      return min;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of values in an array : ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter values in an Araay :");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Max: " + findMax(arr));
    System.out.println("Min: " + findMin(arr));
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work properly, it doesn't give the correct values.
Unless you want to code all from scratch, there are other methods.
Take a look at the following, in fact it is `O(n^2)` for the sort:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
Arrays.sort(arr);
System.out.println("min: "  + arr[0] + " max: " + " " + arr[arr.length - 1];
```

**OR** if it is important that you implement it by your self, you could achieve that with `O(n)`, looping only once.

```
int min = arr[0], max = arr[0];
for(int i= 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
  if(arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
}
System.out.println("min: " + min + " max: " + max);
```